# PHP link only passing part of a mysql result

Tags: php

OK i have a php link which is made up of several variables

```
<a href=\year.php? manufacturer='.$manufacturer.'&fuel_type='.$fuel_type.'&model_type='.$model_type.'>'.$model_type.'</a>
```

The whole code is really long as it has a lot of pagination, so i will just include the basic query and the loop part.

```
$query1 = "SELECT Distinct model_type from $tableName where manufacturer='$manufacturer' AND fuel='$fuel_type' LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
```

And then the bottom part where i get and show the results.

```
 $count = 0;
 $max = 2;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
$model_type = $row['model_type'];               
$count++;
echo '<td class="manu"><div align="center">'.'<a href=\year.php?    manufacturer='.$manufacturer.'&fuel_type='.$fuel_type.'&model_type='.$model_type.'>'.$model_type.'</a>'.'</div></td>';

 if($count >= $max){
  //reset counter
   $count = 0;
  //end and restart
  echo '</tr><tr>';
  }

  }
```

now this works fine except when i take the mode type variable from the database it shows as 1 series, however when it is passed in this link it only gets the 1 and doesn't pick up the series.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide a valid php syntax. It's hard to know if this was part of an existing string

Comment: Which is the "mode type" variable? What is a series? Can you show your database query? And give a sample of the wrong and also the desired URL.

Comment: Probably whitespace issues. Can you post the full code?

Comment: More codes if you please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not shure but you probably have a missing encoding Problem.

try this:

```
<a href="\year.php? manufacturer='.urlencode($manufacturer).'&fuel_type='.urlencode($fuel_type).'&model_type='.urlencode($model_type).'">'.$model_type.'</a>
```

Its url_encoding the values so your url doesnt get broken by ',",spaces and so on.

additional Hint:
Enclose your URL with " or ' so you do not get problems at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass it like:

```
'.urlencode($model_type).'
```

**Try To access it on next page with** `urldecode($_REQUEST['$model_type'])`

Comment: thatnks that returns 5+series and not the 5 series which is in the column